# How to solve this limit problem?-$\lim_{n\to \infty}\ \left(\frac{\ n!}{(mn)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: limits

I need to find the value of-

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\ \left(\frac{\ n!}{(mn)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

where $m {\in} R$

I don't know how to even start. Would someone explain it step by step, also which type of indeterminate form is this?
Is there a simpler to solve this ? i.e. without any high mathematics theorem etc.?

Comment: HInt: If $a_n$ is a positive sequence and $\lim a_n^{1/n}$ exists, then $\lim a_n^{1/n} = \lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ :)

Comment: It should be $m\in\mathbb{R}$, $m>0$. For $m<0$ the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: First write it in the form $(\frac{n!}{(mn)^n})^{1/n} = \frac{1}{m} (\frac{n!}{n^n})^{1/n}$ so that the factor $m$ is a less of a distraction, then look at $\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Use Stirling's approximation for $n!$

$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}( \frac ne)^n$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{(em)^n}\right)^{\frac 1n}$$

$$\frac {1}{em} \lim_{n\to \infty} (2\pi n)^{\frac 1{2n}}$$

Let the above limit (excluding constant) be $L$

$$\log L= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log (2\pi n)}{2n}$$

L'Hopital's rule here

Comment: well i haven't studied that approximation but still thanks.

Comment: @Bubububu_it seems that the approximation didn't work here. Can you tell me when it is applicable?

Comment: @XBOveRLorD What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: the answer is 1/em

Comment: @XBOveRLorD when $n>1$, the approximation is really accurate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @XBOveRLorD Yes, I got confused before. I have already edited my answer, it is indeed $1\over em$

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Stirling.

$ \left(\dfrac{\ n!}{(mn)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
=\dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{mn}
$
so all you need is that
$\dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}
\to \dfrac{1}{e}
$
to get that the limit is
$\dfrac1{em}
$.

$\dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}
\to \dfrac{1}{e}
$
follows from 
$\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n
< n!
<\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{n+1}
$.
These, in turn,
can be proved by induction from
$\left(1+\dfrac1{n}\right)^n
< e
<\left(1+\dfrac1{n}\right)^{n+1}
$.

Comment: Marty, do you know/see another way proving your 2th last inequality than using induction or Stirling? Is there another handy tool one can try?

Comment: Not easily. This kind of inequality, when you do not use logs or calculus or limits, can usually be proved only by induction. Those inequalities bounding n! are elementary and can be very useful (as shown here).

Comment: I was afraid that's the case :/, I always try to get better at manipulating terms, cause I find after some point inductions, L'Hospital or Stirling doesn't add anything to one's knowledge/understanding and thus become more and more the boundary of problems one can solve.

Comment: A fairly crude estimate for $n!$ is adequate because  of the effect of the $n$th root opertion.

Answer (score 1):

let $a_n = \frac {n!}{(mn)^n}$.
by the root-frac analogy we know that for every $a_n$ if the limit of the series $b_n = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ exist it is equal to the limit of the series $c_n = \sqrt[n]{a_n}$. so lets calculate the limit of the series $b_n = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

$b_n = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =  \frac {(n+1)!}{(m((n+1)))^{(n+1)}} : \frac {n!}{(mn)^n} = m^{-1}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$
we know that the limit of $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$ (n goes to infinity) is $e^{-1}$ then the limit of $b_n$ (since m is a constant different than 0) is $m^{-1}e^{-1} = \frac{1}{me}$

final result: $\frac{1}{me}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{(mn)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\ln\left(\left(\frac{n!}{(mn)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right]=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n!}{(mn)^n}\right)}{n}\right]=\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n!}{(mn)^n}\right)}{n}\right]=$$

---

Apply l'Hôpital's rule:

---

$$\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\psi^{(0)}(1+n)-\ln(mn)-1}{1}\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\psi^{(0)}(1+n)-\ln(mn)-1\right)\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[\left(0-\ln(m)-1\right)\right]=\exp\left[-\ln(m)-1\right]=\frac{1}{me}$$

- To find this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\psi^{(0)}(1+n)-\ln(mn)-1\right)$, notice:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\psi^{(0)}(1+n)-\ln(mn)-1\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\psi^{(0)}(1+n)-\ln(mn)\right)-1=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\exp\left[\psi^{(0)}(1+n)\right]}{mn}\right)-1=\ln\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)-1$$

Comment: please explain the l'hospital rule step you used

Comment: @XBOveRLorD Take the derivative of the denominator en nominator and you'll find what I found

Comment: i dont know about that psi or whatever function

Comment: $\psi^{(n)}(x)$ is the derivative of the digamma function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html)

Comment: is there any other way to solve the limit?

Comment: Yes, as Bubububu mentioned!